# Catalog menu bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I create munu like in [this site](https://optimus.aspro-demo.ru/) using bootstrap 4.

[image]

As you can see menu in on sidebar with categories. On mobile mode it collapsed.

Comment: Write some code

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree your question is a bit abstract but here are the main concepts you need to grasp.

With Bootstrap 4 you can create a menu from a [Button Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/button-group/) or a [Vertical Navigation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#vertical).
After properly styling either of those you can have the menu suiting the design.

Regarding the collapsed version for mobile all you need is that the "hamburger button" on top toggles the sliding of the menu (using javascript, for example) and that on mobile devices the menu starts hidden using either [CSS viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) rules or a javascript plugin. **In fact this [plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/web-slide-bootstrap-4-mega-menu-responsive/21299306) does exactly what you need.** *(not affiliated)*